# MiniZinc: Remodel a model with constraints in their solutions

Tags: minizinc

Let this simple model

```
int: n=2;
array [0..(n-1)] of var 0..1 : A_;
array [0..(n-1)] of var 0..1 : B_;
array [0..(n-1)] of var 0..1 : C_;
constraint forall (j in 0..n-1) (
A_[j] + B_[j] = C_[j]
);
```

This model has solutions

```
solution 1:
A_ = array1d(0..1, [0, 0]);
B_ = array1d(0..1, [1, 1]); 
C_ = array1d(0..1, [1, 1]); 
---------- 4
solution 2:
A_ = array1d(0..1, [1, 0]);
B_ = array1d(0..1, [0, 1]);
C_ = array1d(0..1, [1, 1]);
---------- 3
solution 3:
A_ = array1d(0..1, [1, 1]);
B_ = array1d(0..1, [0, 0]);
C_ = array1d(0..1, [1, 1]);
---------- 2
solution 4:
A_ = array1d(0..1, [0, 1]);
B_ = array1d(0..1, [1, 0]);
C_ = array1d(0..1, [1, 1]);
---------- 3
solution 5:
A_ = array1d(0..1, [0, 1]);
B_ = array1d(0..1, [0, 0]);
C_ = array1d(0..1, [0, 1]);
---------- 1
solution 6:
A_ = array1d(0..1, [0, 0]);
B_ = array1d(0..1, [0, 1]);
C_ = array1d(0..1, [0, 1]);
---------- 2
solution 7:
A_ = array1d(0..1, [0, 0]);
B_ = array1d(0..1, [1, 0]);
C_ = array1d(0..1, [1, 0]);
---------- 2
solution 8:
A_ = array1d(0..1, [1, 0]);
B_ = array1d(0..1, [0, 0]);
C_ = array1d(0..1, [1, 0]);
---------- 1
solution 9:
A_ = array1d(0..1, [0, 0]);
B_ = array1d(0..1, [0, 0]);
C_ = array1d(0..1, [0, 0]);
---------- 0
==========
```

How can I remodel it if I want to satisfy the next constraints? I want to introduce some constraints on the set of solutions. Specifically, I would like remodel it to get A such that the sum of the components of their B's and C's solutions is maximum. In this model, for example, the answer will be A = [0, 0], because we have that the sum of the components of the B's and C's (solutions 1, 6, 7, 9) is equal to 4+2+2+0=8.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot model this kind of problem directly in MiniZinc since a MiniZinc model only know its only values (i.e. one solution), not all the possible solutions.

What you can do instead is to use this MiniZinc model to generate all the solutions, and collect them in another system (for example MiniZinc-Python https://pypi.org/project/minizinc/ ) to calculate the optimal solution. If your real problem is similar to your example, it should be fairly easy to just count the components to give that maximum.